# Tikz-Feynman: Particles overlap and appear at only one external leg

Tags: tikz-feynman

#
    I am facing trouble with the tikz-feynman package that I have recently installed. I am currently using LuaTex as the engine in TexLive. Also, I am using a non-English language, so I am using ltjsarticle as my documentclass (this might not be the main problem but I will state it anyway).
    As is said in the title, the main problem is that despite using a sample code from CTAN (or maybe some other site), I get a Feynman diagram that looks like the one posted in this page.
    Here is the code that I have used:

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
    \feynmandiagram [small, horizontal=a to t1] 
        { a [particle=\(\pi^{0}\)] -- [scalar] t1 -- t2 -- t3 -- t1, t2 -- 
        [photon] p1 [particle=\(\gamma\)], t3 -- [photon] p2 [particle=\(\gamma\)], };

    \feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b, red] 
        {a -- b -- {c [particle={\(\alpha\)}], d [particle=\(\beta\)]}
        };

\end{document}
```

I am totally confused. Please help

[image: there are overlaps among the particle letters]

Comment: If you remove `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`, it works fine. (I dunno why, I'm a newcomer to `lualatex`.) It also works if you put `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: There is at least one other place where `lualatex` and `dvipdfmx` appear to interfere, see [p.8 of the `microtype` documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf).

Comment: One more thing: if you put `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` after  `\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}`, this produces an error. If you put `\usepackage{graphicx}`, it again works fine.